# Where is the right place for .tfm, .mf and .sty file?

Tags: texlive, texmaker, updating

I want to to install esvect.sty on my texmaker, I have ubuntu 14.04 and tex live from Ubuntu software center.

I downloaded esvect.zip from this https://ctan.org/pkg/esvect. I follow the README instruction step by step and I already have *.mf  and  *.tfm files but,  where  are the  MFINPUT directory, TFM directory and TEXINPUT directory to put those files ?  I think the correct directory is on /usr/share/texlive.. but I don't know exactly what folders are.

Thank you for read

postscript: I'm really new on this, is the first time i want to install a .sty file, so please be patient with me, I'm sorry for my Grammar, English is not my native language.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Why don't you install this package with `tlmgr`?

Comment: I tried                                                                                                        
 tlmgr install package  esvect                                                                
 but it didn't work, it show:                                                                           
 cannot setup TLPDB in /home/hernando/texmf at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 5336.

Comment: Did it work this way?

Comment: no it didn't, maybe i don't have tlmgr

Comment: `sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-extra`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to install manually a package already included in TeX Live.

It turns out that `esvect` is a member of `texlive-fonts-extra`, so

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-extra
```

will take care of all details.